# How to use find into array of object with react js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, find

I have this block of code:

```
if (el?.children?.length > 0) {
          el?.children?.map((child) => {
            let q_uuid = child?.question?.guid;
            if (
              APDataProps &&
              APDataProps.response &&
              APDataProps.response !== undefined
            ) {
              console.log('q_uuid', q_uuid);
              let response = APDataProps?.response?.find((x) => {
                if (x.guid === q_uuid) {
                  return x;
                }
              });
              console.log('response', response);
              if (response) {
                if (response.comment) {
                  answers = response.comment ? response.comment : '';
                } 
              }
            }
          });
    }
```

my `APDataProps.response` is like that:

[image]

But when I execute this block, I get the value of response `undefined`, but I need on this block the value of `response`

How can I fix the line having find function to get the variable response ?

Comment: Basically, `q_uuid` that isn't equal to  `x.guid`, So `response` is undefined...

Comment: `el?.children?.map(child => APDataProps?.response?.find(x => x.guid === child?.question?.guid)?.comment ?? '')`

Comment: Those code dose same thing, But more readable. Even this code doesn't make any sense if,`APDataProps.response` or `child.question.guid` is undefined... Make sure `el.children` should typeof { question: { guid: "qwerty...." } }[]